# How do you attach a TextFormatter to a TextField?

Tags: javafx, textfield

I am making a simple score sheet and I'm at the phase where I want to let the user create a custom sheet. Obviously I don't want them to just put in any integer willy nilly so I'm trying to connect the UnararyOperator I created to the TextField, but I'm not sure how to do it the way my JavaFX project is set up.

```
public class MainMenuCtrl {
    @FXML
    private TextField playsFld;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> playsValidator = change -> {
            if (change.getText().matches("\\d{1,2,3,4,5,6}")){
                return change;
            } else {
                change.setText("");
                change.setRange(change.getRangeStart(), change.getRangeEnd());
                return change;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: `playsFld.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(playsValidator))`?

Comment: Wonderful. But it doesn't seem to work right with the regex. I have tried three different formulas to only allow putting in one number between 1-6. I can only enter 1-6 but as many times as I want. Any idea?

Comment: `change.getControlNewText.matches("^[1-6]?$")`. You can also modify the range so that whatever is typed is used to replace the existing number. There are lots of examples on this site if you search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out regex is weird and the documentation doesn't always seem to be right. After playing around a bit I found:

```
"(0*(?:[1-9]?)|10)"
```

Means 1-10, but only 1 digit unless it is specifically 10

```
"^[1-6]?$"
```

Means 1-6 and only 1 digit

```
"(0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?)|100)"
```

Means 1-100 up to 3 digits but only a 1 in the hundreds place

*0 is match the preceding character 0 times. I'm pretty sure this is how you lock the number of digits

?: means the preceding character might not show up in the string. I think this makes it so you don't need 01.

[n-n] are for the characters searched. I'm pretty sure [1-9][0-9] in the above are 1-9 for the tens place and 0-9 for the ones. So you could add brackets for every place.

| is for matching any one element. So |100 is to match 100 exactly.

$ is to tell the computer that you have to match before the end.